# didPickMediaItems is returning NULL now for some reason?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mpmediapickercontroller

This worked for a while but now suddenly, it is returning NULL, despite me picking a song each time.

-(void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection

Then an NSLog reveals mediaItemCollection to be empty.

Any ideas why?

Update.. i tried an older version of the app, and it's giving me the same. So it's something to do with the iPod Touch I would guess? That's a worry though. Suggestions?

Comment: I really don't think it's a code problem. Like i said, opening an older version of the app which was running fine causes the problem. Turning the iPod off and on again has no effect.